docker build requires sudo
I have a docker compose project for which I am building containers frequently.  I've read the docker post-install instructions and followed all these steps, and for commands like docker ps and docker compose up, I am able to run these as my normal user account.  However, any time I do a build -- whether docker build . or docker compose build or docker compose up --build -- the process errors out.  I was lucky to discover that adding sudo before any of these commands makes them work properly, but it can be very annoying to have to do this for something that seems to have no real security implication, and is not the case on Windows (on my Windows 10 PC, I can run any docker commands in a non-elevated shell, no admin or other sudo-equivalent required).
Is there a way to configure my environment so that docker build does not require sudo to run successfully?  If there are security concerns to doing so, can I restrict this ability to only my project folder (and does that mitigate security concerns)?
Specific error when running docker build . in a directory with a dockerfile:
ERROR: permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Head "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/_ping": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied

Different error with docker compose build:
[+] Building 0.7s (6/6) FINISHED                                                                                                                                            docker:default
 => [server internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.33kB                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => [server internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => ERROR [server internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.12.2                                                                                                         0.6s
 => [node internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [node internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 802B                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => ERROR [node internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:latest                                                                                                             0.6s
------
 > [server internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.12.2:
------
------
 > [node internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:latest:
------
failed to solve: node: error getting credentials - err: exec: "docker-credential-desktop": executable file not found in $PATH, out: ``


Can you show the actual output and error from a docker build that fails? Use some simple Dockerfile

@muru good point, just added a version of it.  I think compose typically gives me a different error but the one I just posted is the one it's giving right now

Restart got my old familiar error back, just edited it in.

Can you check whether your user is in the docker group using groups $USER?? If not, can you add it using sudo usermod -aG docker $USER followed by newgrp and recheck the commands??

For your docker compose bulid issue, changing credsStore to credStore in ~/.docker/config.json might help

Yes, my user is in the docker group.  I updated the config.json as you said, I am not getting the following with docker build .:  ERROR: failed to solve: node: error getting credentials - err: exec: "docker-credential-credStore": executable file not found in $PATH, out: \``
